# Access function in module with similar name of function in another module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Code:

```
for (var i in RESTCalls_GET) {
    describe('Retrieve all Product Component names and their IDs', function() {
        var restCalls;
        beforeEach(function() {
            RESTCalls_GET.setClient(mockClient);
            restCalls = new Rest_calls(mockClient);
        });
        describe(i + '()', function() {
            it('should return data if response code is 200', function(done) {
                mockClient.mockURLForSucceed(eval('restCalls.' + i + "_RESTCall"), eval('RESTCalls_GET_ExampleData.' + i + "_ExampleData"), 200);
                eval('RESTCalls_GET.' + i)(function(result) {
                    result.should.equal(eval('RESTCalls_GET_ExampleData.' + i + "_ExampleData"));
                    done();
                });
            }),
            it('should return error if response code is NOT 200', function(done) {
                mockClient.mockURLForError(eval('restCalls.' + i + "_RESTCall"), null, TestData.RESTCallResponseError_Test);
                eval('RESTCalls_GET.' + i)(function(errorObj) {
                    errorObj.should.have.property('errorCode');
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I am looping though functions in `RESTCalls_GET`. Say, for example, `i = getComponent`, a function called `getComponent_RESTCall` will be in module `restCalls`

I have been told that one way to accomplish this is by using **eval()** (even though it is not recommended). This way is not working and when I debug, the parameters which use eval() in `mockURLForSucceed` are `undefined`.

This obviously causes all my tests to fail.

Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT:** *(additional information)*

```
var mockClient = function() {
    var urlMap = {};
    return {
        get: function(url, callback) {
            var entry = urlMap[url];
            if (entry) {
                callback(entry[0], entry[1]);
            } else {
                console.error("Unable to match URL " + url);
            }
            return {
                on: function() {                  
                    //Ignore
                }
            };
        },
        mockURLForSucceed: function(URLofRESTCall, succeedData, succeedRes)    {
            urlMap[URLofRESTCall] = [succeedData, {statusCode: succeedRes}];
        },
        mockURLForError: function(URLofRESTCall, errorData, errorRes) {
            urlMap[URLofRESTCall] = [errorData, errorRes];
        }
    }
}();
```

**EDIT:** *(half way there)*

I've resorted back to eval() an got the function/variable name required in format *file.functionName* by this:

```
var RESTCallURL     = eval('"restCalls." + i + "_RESTCall"');
var RESTCallData    = eval('"RESTCalls_GET_ExampleData." + i + "_ExampleData"');
```

The problem I'm having now if that these are strings. So when I pass them into a function, it gets that string value and not the one it equals in it's own function, does that make sense?

What I mean is that if I passed in `RESTCallURL` into a function now, then the value of that parameter would be `restCalls.whatever_RESTCall` whereas before it got the URL of the REST Call I am calling (`http://whatever`). Since I now have the name of the function, am I able to search for functions in my project by that name?

This task seems so simple to do and I think I am over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `eval` there, what about using

```
RESTCalls_GET[i](function(result) {
  result.should.equal(RESTCalls_GET_ExampleData[i + '_ExampleData']));
  done();
});
```

You could easily test this behaviour by defining the following in your browser console

```
var test = {
  'some-function': function() { console.log('works'); }
};
test['some-function']();
```

Comment: This has improved the situation as the function `mockURLForSucceed` is actually executing now. However. the parameters for it `URLofRESTCall` and `succeedData` are undefined. I will edit my post so you can see that function